# Rails 5: db:migrate fails with globalize gem PG::UndefinedTable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, globalize

I am trying to upgrade a Rails app from 4.2 to 5.1.

The gems I am currently using:

- gem 'activerecord, '5.1.4
- gem 'globalize', '5.1.0.beta2'

In my **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'globalize', git: 'https://github.com/globalize/globalize'
gem 'activemodel-serializers-xml'
gem 'globalize-accessors'
gem 'globalize3_helpers', git: 'https://github.com/mathieumahe/globalize3_helpers.git'
```

I have a migration file that looks like this:

```
class CreateQuotas < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :quotas do |t|
      t.references :survey, index: true
      t.integer :target, default: 0
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up { Quota.create_translation_table!(title: :string) }
      dir.down { Quota.drop_translation_table! }
    end
  end
end
```

and the appropriate `translations` directive is set in the **quota.rb** model:

```
class Quota < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  translates :title
  # ...
end
```

Running the migration is resulting in the following error:

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "quota" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"quota"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
                     c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
                FROM pg_attribute a
                LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
                LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"quota"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Am I doing something incorrectly or did I miss something obvious?

**UPDATE:**

I've made some progress on this. I've input the SQL directly into the migration, so it looks something like this:

```
class CreateQuotas < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :quotas do |t|
      t.references :survey, index: true
      t.integer :target, default: 0
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        execute <<-SQL
          SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
               pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
               c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
          FROM pg_attribute a
          LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
          LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
          LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
         WHERE a.attrelid = '"quotas"'::regclass
           AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
         ORDER BY a.attnum
        SQL
      end
      # dir.up do
      #   Quota.create_translation_table! :title => :string
      # end
      #
      dir.down do
        Quota.drop_translation_table!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This seems to work.

Essentially, the `Quota.create_translation_table! :title => :string` directive is singularizing `'"quota"'::regclass` which causes the failure. It passes with `'"quotas"'::regclass`, which is not being inferred from the class name :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much head-scratching, I've realized what the issue is.

Rails 4 allowed a singularized `Quota` model to be pluralized to `quotas`. Rails 5 singularizes `Quotum` and pluralizes it to `quota`.

This explains the `'"quota"'::regclass` error, and why forcing it to `'"quotas"'::regclass` prevented the migration from failing.

Renaming all models and migrations (`Quota` to `Quotum` and `quotas` to `quota`) fixes this issue in Rails 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

If your activerecord version is 5.1.4, try this:

```
class CreateQuotas < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
```

Comment: That makes no difference :(

Comment: @DaniG2k Few days ago, i got same error when i used migration without version: `ActiveRecord::Migration`

Comment: The one that I already have, `class CreateQuotas < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]` should suffice.

Comment: @DaniG2k Ok. Try to create two migrations. First with "create_table" only and run db:migrate. After this create separate migration for "reversible" change.

Comment: I tried this as well, doesn't make a difference :( by the way, every time I run the migrations I'm doing a full `for i in drop create migrate; do RAILS_ENV=test rails db:$i; done;` so it should completely run all the migrations from a fresh database.

Comment: @DaniG2k One more thing, run with schema loading `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load`

Comment: That seems to run but it assumes I have a `schema.rb` file and wouldn't be great for newcomers to the project. I think it's best to get the migrations running in order.